# Is the CSS english naming appropriate and need to be modified?

Tags: css, html-table, naming

### Is the CSS English naming appropriate and need to be modified?

Is writing a **table template**, my English is weak.
**Is the CSS (class="xxx") English name suitable?**

#### What needs to be modified?

Whether it is English grammar or description, hope to get some suggestions for revision.

Thanks

```
<!-- =table: start -->
<table class="list-table-m" summary="summary">
    <caption>table caption</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="col-id">
                <a class="sort sort-asc-active" href="#">
                    <i class="icon icon-sort-asc"></i>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-user-number-name"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-user-number-id"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-dept-office"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-title"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-describe"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-price">
                <a class="sort sort-desc-active" href="#">
                    <i class="icon icon-sort-desc"></i>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-date-full"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-state"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-edit"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- =table: end -->

<!-- =cell data: start -->
<span class="text-user-number-name">
    <i class="number"></i>
    <span class="name"></span>
</span>
<span class="text-user-number-id">
    <i class="number"></i>
    <i class="id"></i>
</span>
<span class="text-dept-office">
    <span class="dept"></span>
    <span class="office"></span>
</span>
<span class="text-user-number-name-inline">
    <i class="number"></i>
    <span class="name"></span>
</span>
<span class="text-user-number-id-inline">
    <i class="number"></i>
    <i class="id"></i>
</span>
<span class="text-dept-office-inline">
    <span class="dept"></span>
    <span class="office"></span>
</span>
<p class="cell-title"></p>
<p class="textarea-m"></p>
<i class="text-price"></i>
<span class="date-full">
    <i class="df-date"></i>
    <i class="df-time"></i>
</span>
<span class="date-df"></span>
<span class="time-df"></span>
<span class="operate-area">
    <!-- <a class="link-xxx" href="#"> -->
        <i class="icon icon-view"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-delete"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-success"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-remove"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-lock"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-unlock"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-link"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-share"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-refresh"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-upload"></i>
        <i class="icon icon-download"></i>
    <!-- </a> -->
</span>
<!-- =cell data: end -->
```

Comment: It's quite an opinionated topic but there are a few existing naming conventions that you can try to follow. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849

Comment: You can check this [link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/css-naming-conventions-that-will-save-you-hours-of-debugging-35cea737d849) for some css naming conventions. In any case, the name you give to a style class should be as representative as it can be, so any person that sees that name has an idea of what it is about or to what html element it is destined to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter what you name your classes, as long as *you* know what they do and mean. It can sometimes be hard to come up with good class names, but as long as you aren't giving the code away for someone else to read, it's okay.

However, I do suggest that if you only use a class once, like `col-price` or `col-describe`, use `id` instead, since it's more "correct".